# Ionic native plugin - platform check - to prevent code break in browser when run via 'ionic serve'

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I am new to ionic development and am using the below code (on button click event) to ensure that the native plugin call code doesn't break/error out when executing on web browser using 'ionic serve':

```
if (!this.platform.is('cordova')) {
    console.warn('Push notifications not initialized. Cordova is not available - Run in physical device');
    return;
  }
--other wise run the native code..
```

My question is - when this runs on a real device, what exactly is the output of the if check? For Android and iOS is the platform cordova? Should I also be writing if check for this.platform.is('Android') and this.platform.is('iOS') also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Depending on the platform the user is on, `is(platformName)` will
>   return `true` or `false`. Note that the same app can return `true` for
>   more than one platform name. For example, an app running from an iPad
>   would return `true` for the platform names: `mobile`, `ios`, `ipad`,
>   and `tablet`. Additionally, if the app was running from Cordova then
>   `cordova` would be true, and if it was running from a web browser on
>   the iPad then `mobileweb` would be `true`.

Now to answer your questions

***when this runs on a real device, what exactly is the output of the if check?***

If you are application(android,ios,windows) is built using the cordova framework and installed into the respective devices, then this.platform.is('cordova') would return true.

On the other hand, If you host the application on any web server and try accessing it through your mobile browser, then this.platform.is('cordova') would return false.

***For Android and iOS is the platform cordova***?

Yes, only if you have created the native application( .apk , .ipa ) from cordova framework.

If you are accessing the web application in the browser from your mobile device, then the platform is not cordova.

***Should I also be writing if check for this.platform.is('Android') and this.platform.is('iOS') also?***

Depends on the situation, In most of the cases if you have generated the native application( .apk, .ipa ) from cordova framework and you have some generic code for both the platforms then this.platform.is('cordova') is enough.

You can check the following table for reference

```
 | Platform Name   | Description                        |
 * |-----------------|------------------------------------|
 * | android         | on a device running Android.       |
 * | cordova         | on a device running Cordova.       |
 * | core            | on a desktop device.               |
 * | ios             | on a device running iOS.           |
 * | ipad            | on an iPad device.                 |
 * | iphone          | on an iPhone device.               |
 * | mobile          | on a mobile device.                |
 * | mobileweb       | in a browser on a mobile device.   |
 * | phablet         | on a phablet device.               |
 * | tablet          | on a tablet device.                |
 * | windows         | on a device running Windows.       |
```

**Reference**:https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/platform/Platform/

Comment: Assuming the code to call native function is present in a provider (that calls native methods), should platform check be done at page level or provider level?

Comment: Provider level. For one good reason, if you want to modify the platform check in future it would be easy to change it in one place rather than changing it in all the pages. I would go for that approach. I'm not sure which is right or wrong.